# Do html events pass any variables to event handlers?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, in vb.net, each event can optionally give you the object that raised the event and various other misc data in xxEventArgs. I'm wondering if you could get something similar in javascript? I couldn't find any documentation about that while googling.

EDIT: just did a quick test and added a variable to the event handler function, apparently something does get passed called [object MouseEvent] in this case, is there any info on whats in it?

Comment: [MDN documentation on Event objects.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

Comment: MDN.io is an excellent resource for basic questions like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

Comment: oh great, a lot of useful stuff in there apparently that I've previously been getting the dumb way. Can anybody vouch for whether or not they are cross browser compatible?

Comment: @JakeFreelander they're not exactly the same, especially in Internet Explorer. Libraries like jQuery generally wrap native Event objects in a wrapper that *is* consistent across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

What's being passed is an **[Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event)** object, or any of its extending objects. The Event object does contain any and all relevant information about the event.

This convention is supported by all browsers, although some elements of the Event might be different in *ahm* **some** browsers.